# Int and str changing every letter with error + EDIT: zero indexing eachword

Tags: python

My goal is to write a function which change every even letter into upper letter and odd to lower (space also count as a one element).

This is my code

```
def to_weird_case(s):
    
    for i in s:
        if len(i) % 2 == 0:
            s[i] = i.upper() + s(i+1)
        else:
            s[i] = i.lower() + s(i+2)
        
        
        return i
```

I think it should be quite correct, but it gives me error.

```
 line 7, in to_weird_case
    s[i] = i.lower() + s(str(i)+2)
 TypeError: must be str, not int
```

EDIT:

I have a sugesstion but I don't know how to make it. I try it for myself and back here.

This needs to definitly explicietly state that the zero indexing uppercase is for each word.
Do you know guys how to make it?

Comment: What argument do you feed to you function?

Comment: Print out `i` during your for loop, it looks like you're unsure what it is. Also, using return in a for loop will stop it after the first iteration. What is your expected output?

Comment: If my input is This it will output into ThIs, so first and third letter change into upper letter, so I see now I need to rechane the code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So we can analyze your code and just explain what you typed:

```
def to_weird_case(s):    
    for i in s: # s is your string, and i is the actual character
        if len(i) % 2 == 0: # if your length of the character can be divided by 2. Hmm this is weird
            s[i] = i.upper() + s(i+1) # s[i] change a character in the string but you should provide an index (i) so an integer and not a character. But this is not supported in Python.
        else:
            s[i] = i.lower() + s(i+2)
        
        
        return i # This will exit after first iteraction, so to_weird_case("this") will return "t".
```

So what you need to is first create a output string and fill that. And when iteration over s, you want the index of the char and the char value itself.

```
def to_weird_case(s):    
  output = ""
  for i, myChar in enumerate(s):
      if i % 2 == 0:
          output += myChar.upper()
      else:
          output += myChar.lower()

  return output

my_sentence = "abcdef"
print(to_weird_case(my_sentence))
```

And when you want to ignore spaces, you need to keep track of actual characters (excluding spaces)

```
def to_weird_case(s):
  output = ""

  count = 0  
  for myChar in s:
    if myChar.isspace():      
      output += myChar
    else:
      if count % 2 == 0:
          output += myChar.upper()
      else:
          output += myChar.lower()
      count += 1

  return output

my_sentence = "abc def"
print(to_weird_case(my_sentence))
```

Comment: Thanks! it helps me a lot to understand more.
In fact it is weird. To specify I wanted to write if it is second character it is number 2, if 4th character it is devided 2 as well so It goes upper.

Comment: If have sentence like this it doesn't work: This is a test it gives me ThIs iS A TeSt and its not correct.

Comment: hmm, I think last question.
How to forget about spaces and dont take them under consideration?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: upper/lower on a space has no affect to it really does not matter. But what you could do is check if the myChar is a space (and do that before the initial if)

Comment: Yes, but I see space between word make the wrong output at the end look:
'JuSt kIdDiNg' should equal 'JuSt KiDdInG'
Do you have any sugestions cuz of that?

Comment: I have a sugesstion but I don't know how to make it. I try it for myself and maybe later back here.

This needs to definitly explicietly state that the zero indexing uppercase is for each word.

Comment: @Vidar567 If you use the split method to split the string in a list words, you could then perform the change of case on each work and then join list back together again.

Comment: @Vidar567 I've editted my answer to show how to perform this action on each word.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do in a single line using a list comprehension

```
def funny_case(s):
    return "".join([c.upper() if idx%2==0 else c.lower() for idx,c in enumerate(s)])
```

If you want to treat each word separately then you can split it up in to a list of words and "funny case" each word individually, see below code

```
original = "hello world"

def funny_case(s):
    return "".join([c.upper() if idx%2==0 else c.lower() for idx,c in enumerate(s) ])

def funny_case_by_word(s):
    return " ".join((funny_case(word) for word in s.split()))
    
   
print(funny_case_by_word(original))
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this yourself

```
def to_weird_case(s):

    for i in s:
        print (i)
```

After doing this you will find that i gives you characters.

```
if len(i) % 2 == 0:
```

This line is incorrect as you are trying to find the length of a single character. len(s) would be much better.

So the code will be like

```
def to_weird_case(s):
    s2 = "" #We create another string as strings are immutable in python
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            s2 = s2 + s[i].upper()
        else:
            s2 = s2 + s[i].lower()
    return s2
```

Comment: More idiomatic would be to use `enumerate(s)` instead of iterating over the indices in `range(len(s))`

Answer (score 1):

From @RvdK analysis, you'ld have seen where corrections are needed. In addition to what has been pointed out, I want you to note that `s[i]` will work fine only if `i` is an integer, but in your case where (by assumption) `i` is a string you'll encounter several TypeErrors. From my understanding of what you want to do, it should go this way:

```
def to_weird_case(s):

for i in s:
    if s.index(i) % 2 == 0:
        s[s.index(i)] = i.upper() + s[s.index(i)]
    elif s.index(i) % 2 == 1:
        s[s.index(i)] = i.lower() + s[s.index(i)] 
       
return i # or possibly return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code is as follows

```
def case(s):
     
    txt=''

    for i in range(len(s)):
    
        if i%2==0:
            txt+=s[i].upper()
        else:
            txt+=s[i].lower()
    
    return txt
```

String assignment gives error in Python therefore i recommend considering my approach

Answer (score 0):

When looping over elements of `s`, you get the letter itself, not its index. You can use `enumerate` to get both index and letter.

```
def to_weird_case(s):
    result = ''
    for index, letter in enumerate(s):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            result += letter.upper()
        else:
            result += letter.lower()
    
     return result
```

Comment: Gustave, could you tell me why you have used two parameters instead of one?
Thanks

Comment: @Vidar567 enumerate returns a tuple (2 values), first is the index and the second is the value.

Answer (score 0):

correct code:

```
def to_weird_case(s):
        str2 = ""
        s.split() # through splitting string is converted to list as it is easy to traverse through list
        for i in range(0,len(s)):
            n = s[i] # storing value in n
            if(i % 2 == 0):
                str2 = str2 + n.upper()
            else:
                str2 = str2 + n.lower()
        return str2 
str1 = "hello world"
r = to_weird_case(str1)
print(r)
```